# Parallelized bootstrapping with replacement with xarray/dask

Tags: multiprocessing, dask, resampling, python-xarray

I want to perform N=1000 bootstrapping with replacement on gridded data. One computation takes about 0.5s. I have access to a supercomputer exclusive node with 48 cores. Because the resampling are independent of each other, I naively hope to distribute the workload on all or at least many cores and get a performance increase by .8 * ncores. But I dont get it.

I still lack proper understand about dask. Based on [Best practices in setting number of dask workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099685/best-practices-in-setting-number-of-dask-workers), I use:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(processes=False, threads_per_worker=8, n_workers=6, memory_limit=‘32GB')
```

I also tried with SLURMCluster, but I guess I first need to understand what I do and then scale.

My MWE:

1. create sample data
2. write function I want to apply
3. write resampling inits function
4. write bootstrapping function with bootstrap (=N) as argument: see many implementations below
5. perform bootstrapping

```
import dask
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from dask.distributed import Client

inits = np.arange(50)
lats = np.arange(96)
lons = np.arange(192)
data = np.random.rand(len(inits), len(lats), len(lons))
a = xr.DataArray(data,
                        coords=[inits, lats, lons],
                        dims=['init', 'lat', 'lon'])

data = np.random.rand(len(inits), len(lats), len(lons))
b = xr.DataArray(data,
                        coords=[inits, lats, lons],
                        dims=['init', 'lat', 'lon'])

def func(a,b, dim='init'):
    return (a-b).std(dim)

bootstrap=96

def resample(a):
    smp_init = np.random.choice(inits, len(inits))
    smp_a = a.sel(init=smp_init)
    smp_a['init'] = inits
    return smp_a


# serial function
def bootstrap_func(bootstrap=bootstrap):
    res = (func(resample(a),b) for _ in range(bootstrap))
    res = xr.concat(res,'bootstrap')
    # leave out quantile because not issue here yet
    #res_ci = res.quantile([.05,.95],'bootstrap')
    return res


@dask.delayed
def bootstrap_func_delayed_decorator(bootstrap=bootstrap):
    return bootstrap_func(bootstrap=bootstrap)


def bootstrap_func_delayed(bootstrap=bootstrap):
    res = (dask.delayed(func)(resample(a),b) for _ in range(bootstrap))
    res = xr.concat(dask.compute(*res),'bootstrap')
    #res_ci = res.quantile([.05,.95],'bootstrap')
    return res

for scheduler in ['synchronous','distributed','multiprocessing','processes','single-threaded','threads']:
    print('scheduler:',scheduler)

    def bootstrap_func_delayed_processes(bootstrap=bootstrap):
        res = (dask.delayed(func)(resample(a),b) for _ in range(bootstrap))
        res = xr.concat(dask.compute(*res, scheduler=scheduler),'bootstrap')
        res = res.quantile([.05,.95],'bootstrap')
        return res

    %time c = bootstrap_func_delayed_processes()
```

The following results are from my 4 core laptop. But on the supercomputer I also see no speedup, rather decrease by 50%.

Results for serial:

```
%time c = bootstrap_func()
CPU times: user 814 ms, sys: 58.7 ms, total: 872 ms
Wall time: 862 ms
```

Results for parallel:

```
%time c = bootstrap_func_delayed_decorator().compute()
CPU times: user 96.2 ms, sys: 50 ms, total: 146 ms
Wall time: 906 ms
```

Results for parallelized from the loop:

```
scheduler: synchronous
CPU times: user 2.57 s, sys: 330 ms, total: 2.9 s
Wall time: 2.95 s
scheduler: distributed
CPU times: user 4.51 s, sys: 2.74 s, total: 7.25 s
Wall time: 8.86 s
scheduler: multiprocessing
CPU times: user 4.18 s, sys: 2.53 s, total: 6.71 s
Wall time: 7.95 s
scheduler: processes
CPU times: user 3.97 s, sys: 2.1 s, total: 6.07 s
Wall time: 7.39 s
scheduler: single-threaded
CPU times: user 2.26 s, sys: 275 ms, total: 2.54 s
Wall time: 2.47 s
scheduler: threads
CPU times: user 2.84 s, sys: 341 ms, total: 3.18 s
Wall time: 2.66 s
```

Expected results:
- speedup (by .8 * ncores)

Other considerations:
- I also checked whether I should chunk my data. too sample chunks. chunked arrays take longer.

My questions:
- What did I get wrong about dask parallelization?
- Is the client setup not useful that way?
- Did I implement dask.delayed not clever enough?
- Is my serial function already executed in parallel because of dask? I think not.

Comment: dude you're not alone. I am so much into making this thing work! :|

Comment: you should set up a bounty for it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much faster solution with multidimensional indexing

https://xskillscore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/xskillscore.core.resampling.resample_iterations_idx.html#xskillscore.core.resampling.resample_iterations_idx

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this. When posting this challenge, I obviously didn't understand a few aspects of it:

- I ran the timings on a laptop with two physical cores. This doesn't allow much parallelization in a CPU-bound problem. Now I ran this on a node with 48 logical CPUs
- I should have thought about which parts of the algorithm are easily [parallelizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) and which parts are not. Only then I can chunk accordingly.

See my solution here: https://gist.github.com/aaronspring/118abd7b9bf81e555b1fced42eef427f

The game-changers wrt. the code posted initially:

- I chunk a dimension (here `x`) with is not involved in the func (which uses `time`)
- I still use the client as mentioned above: [Best practices in setting number of dask workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099685/best-practices-in-setting-number-of-dask-workers)
- I only try to parallelize the iteration part. The quantile method is done in memory.

Conclusion: It is simpler than expected. The gist shows an implementation with `dask.delayed` and `dask.futures` but thats not even needed in my use case. First try to understand parallelism https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/ and read the dask documentation https://dask.org/.